# Python line.split between two delimeters

Tags: python, delimiter

I have a text file that contains the following data:

```
Schema:
  Column Name                   Localized Name                Type    MaxLength
  ----------------------------  ----------------------------  ------  ---------
  Raw                Binary            Binary  16384

Row 1:
  Binary:
-----BEGIN-----
fdsfdsfdasadsad
fsdfafsdafsadfa
fsdafadsfadsfdsa
-----END-----


Row 2:
  Binary:
-----BEGIN-----
fsdfdssd
fdsfadsfasd
fsdafdsa 
-----END-----


Row 3:
  Binary:
-----BEGIN-----
fsdafadsds
fsdafasdsda
fdsafadssad
-----END-----
```

I need to extract the data between the "-----BEGIN-----" and "------END-----" delimiters into an array.

This is what I've tried:

```
data = open("test_data.txt", 'r')
result = [line.split('-----BEGIN-----') for line in data.readlines()]
print data
```

However this obviously gets all of the data after the '-----BEGIN-----' delimiter.

How can I add the end delimeter ?

Note the file is quite large, arround about 1GB.

Comment: Does this exactly represents that data in your input `.txt` file

Comment: Updated to reflect real use case. There are multiple lines within the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multiple lines between and you want the data separated into sections just catch each block beginning with -----BEGIN-.. and keep adding lines until you reach `END`:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    out = []
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip() == "-----BEGIN-----":
            tmp = []
            for line in f:
                if line.rstrip() == "-----END-----":
                    out.append(tmp)
                    break
                tmp.append(line)
```

The sections will be split into sublists:

```
 [['fdsfdsfdasadsad\n', 'fsdfafsdafsadfa\n', 'fsdafadsfadsfdsa\n'],   ['fsdfdssd\n', 'fdsfadsfasd\n', 'fsdafdsa \n'], ['fsdafadsds\n', 'fsdafasdsda\n', 'fdsafadssad\n']]
```

Use `with` to open your files and don't call readlines unless you want a list, you can iterate over the file object as above without storing all the content in memory.

Or using `itertools.takewhile` to get the sections :

```
from itertools import takewhile, imap
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f = imap(str.rstrip,f) # use map for python3
    out = [list(takewhile(lambda x: x != "-----END-----",f)) for line in f if line == "-----BEGIN-----"]
    print(out)

[['fdsfdsfdasadsad', 'fsdfafsdafsadfa', 'fsdafadsfadsfdsa'], 
['fsdfdssd', 'fdsfadsfasd', 'fsdafdsa'], 
['fsdafadsds', 'fsdafasdsda', 'fdsafadssad']]
```

If you want a single list of all the words you can chain:

```
from itertools import takewhile,chain, imap
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f = imap(str.rstrip,f)
    out = chain.from_iterable(takewhile(lambda x: x != "-----END-----",f) for line in f if line == "-----BEGIN-----")
    print(list(out))

['fdsfdsfdasadsad', 'fsdfafsdafsadfa', 'fsdafadsfadsfdsa',
 'fsdfdssd', 'fdsfadsfasd', 'fsdafdsa', 'fsdafadsds', 'fsdafasdsda', 'fdsafadssad']
```

A file object returns its own iterator so every time we iterate or call takewhile we consume lines, takewhile will keep taking lines until we hit `-----END----` then we continue iterating until we hit another `-----BEGIN-----` line, if the lines always start with `-` and no other lines do then you can just check for that condition i.e `if line[0] == "-"` and `x[0] != "-"` instead of check the full line.

If you wanted to process each section you could use a generator expression and work on the lines from each section:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f = imap(str.rstrip,f)
    out = ((takewhile(lambda x: x != "-----END-----",f)) for line in f if line == "-----BEGIN-----")
    for sec in out:
        print(list(sec))

['fdsfdsfdasadsad', 'fsdfafsdafsadfa', 'fsdafadsfadsfdsa']
['fsdfdssd', 'fdsfadsfasd', 'fsdafdsa']
['fsdafadsds', 'fsdafasdsda', 'fdsafadssad']
```

If you want a single string call join:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    f = imap(str.rstrip,f)
    st, end = "-----BEGIN-----", "-----END-----"
    out = "".join(chain.from_iterable(takewhile(lambda x: x != end,f)
                                      for line in f if line == st))
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
fdsfdsfdasadsadfsdfafsdafsadfafsdafadsfadsfdsafsdfdssdfdsfadsfasdfsdafdsafsdafadsdsfsdafasdsdafdsafadssad
```

To get a single string keeping `-----BEGIN-----` and `-----END-----`

```
with open("out.txt") as f:
    f = imap(str.rstrip,f)
    st, end = "-----BEGIN-----", "-----END-----"
    out = "".join(["{}{}{}".format(st, "".join(takewhile(lambda x: x != end, f)), end)
                                    for line in f if line == st])
```

Output:

```
-----BEGIN-----fdsfdsfdasadsadfsdfafsdafsadfafsdafadsfadsfdsa-----END----------BEGIN-----fsdfdssdfdsfadsfasdfsdafdsa-----END----------BEGIN-----fsdafadsdsfsdafasdsdafdsafadssad-----END-----
```

Comment: @user1513388, no worries, if you don't want each section separately you don't have to use lists.

Comment: Thanks - Actually yes, I don't need each section separately. I need a single block. Whats the recomended way to do this?

Comment: @user1513388, the chain method, if you want all the strings joined use str.join instead of the list call

Comment: Sorry not sure I'm with you - would you mind sharing an example :)

Comment: Based on the above examples if I wanted to keep the -----BEGIN----- and -----END----- blocks along with the content. How would I achieve that ?

Comment: You already know the sections so it is just a matter of adding those strings to the start and end, I will add the code in a bit, only a matter of str.join and str.format

Comment: Thanks - appreciate that

Comment: Thanks - one final question. If I need to pass the contents of each of the blocks into a Jinja2 template can I do this as I iterate through the contents of the file ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
array1 =[]
with open('test_data.txt','r') as infile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip() == "-----BEGIN-----":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "-----END-----":
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            array1.append(line)
```

This will solve your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is small enough to load the whole thing into memory, then using a Regular Expression (aka regex) is probably the best approach.

```
import re

beginstr = '\n-----BEGIN-----\n'
endstr = '-----END-----\n'
pat = re.compile(beginstr + '(.*?\n)' + endstr, re.DOTALL)

with open('test_data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

result = pat.findall(data)
for row in result:
    print repr(row)
```

**output**

```
'fdsfdsfdasadsad\nfsdfafsdafsadfa\nfsdafadsfadsfdsa\n'
'fsdfdssd\nfdsfadsfasd\nfsdafdsa \n'
'fsdafadsds\nfsdafasdsda\nfdsafadssad\n'
```

That code creates a compiled regex pattern; it's not strictly necessary in this case, since we're only using the pattern once, but it does make the code look neater, IMHO.

That regex looks for substrings delimited by `'beginstr'` and `'\n' + endstr`. The `findall` call only captures the stuff between those delimiters, due to use of the grouping parentheses. I've put a `'\n'` inside those parentheses so that the captured substrings will always have a trailing newline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.ifilter` :

```
from itertools import ifilter
with open('a1.txt') as f,open('a1.txt') as g :
    f.next()
    it=f
    print [i.strip() for i in ifilter(lambda x:next(f).strip()=='-----END-----',g)]
```

result :

```
['fdsfdsfdasadsad', 'fsdfdssd', 'fsdafadsds']
```

If the file is not huge use `re.findall` :

```
>>> re.findall('-----BEGIN-----\n(.*?)\n-----END-----',open('file_name').read(),re.M|re.DOTALL)
['fdsfdsfdasadsad', 'fsdfdssd', 'fsdafadsds']
```

Or without `itertools` you can use following recipe :

```
with open('a1.txt') as f,open('a1.txt') as g :
    f.next()
    it=f
    for line in g :
        n=next(f)
        try :
            if n.strip()=='-----END-----':
                print line
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

result :

```
fdsfdsfdasadsad

fsdfdssd

fsdafadsds
```

Note that a file object is an iterator you can get the next item from the it by `next` function in each iteration. so we compare the next line of each line in our file with its next line (stripped)if it's equal to `'-----END-----'` we print it.

Answer (score 0):

`split` alone is just fine, no need for other tools. Just also split off the end marker and everything after it:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    blocks = [part.split('-----END-----')[0].strip()
              for part in f.read().split('-----BEGIN-----')[1:]]
```

Comment: what is s supposed to be?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `f.read()`. For once I don't use an actual file and right away I screw up :-). Thanks, fixed.